# controller refs of element encapsuled

Tags: javascript, extjs

I work with sencha architect and extjs 4.2.0

I need to put an alias to a gridPanel for have a ref in my controller.

When i try to create a custom property named alias : i can't because createAlias exists and this replace the xtype and and error (name is undefined).

I supose because i can't attribute a widget alias in my encapsuled elements inverse of a unique view of a unique element.

I supose my viewport have an alias but how get the viewport element and the specify function of the ref controller create when use it ...

My gridPanel in my viewport :

```
    {
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    id: 'GridUtilisateursApplicatifs',
    store: 'UtilisateursApplicatifs',
  columns: [
................
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already giving it an id, you don't need an alias.

Use either:

`Ext.getCmp('id'); // No need for a ref in your controller`

`selector: '#id'; // For the ref`

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you set the `itemId` property

```
itemId: "GridUtilisateursApplicatifs"
```

and select your component so

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#GridUtilisateursApplicatifs");
```